# Transparent video element

Tags: html, video, aframe

How could I achieve transparent video elements?

I've read that webm (VP8) supports alpha transparency. That limits my project to Chrome on desktop.

I was looking to build a VR experience for phones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use A-Frame. Some options:

```
<a-video opacity="0.8">
<a-videosphere opacity="0.8">
<a-entity geometry="primitive: plane" material="src: url(video.webm); opacity: 0.8"
```

https://aframe.io/

Comment: I should have phrased it better. Alpha channel. Not changing the entire objects transparency.

Comment: Does `transparent="true"` or `material="transparent: true"` work? It works for PNGs so maybe for videos as well.

Comment: That's the thing. I'm using A-Frame and wanted to use videos with alpha channels.